# Text to Columns feature finding second space

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible to split on the second space only? I am looking for a method that doesn't require VBA, however, I will use it if that is the most effective option.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

Replace the first space with a unique character or expression (e.g. [rep]):

`SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","[REP]", 1)`

Convert text to columns.

Replace the previous expression back to space:
`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[REP]", " ")`.

Another two step solution would be split the text to columns, getting 3 columns, and then concatenate the two first columns, separated by a space. (e.g. `=A6&" "&B6`)

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE` replaces all occurrences by default, if you want to replace only first one, then use `SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","[REP]",1)`

Comment: @Máté: You're right. Fixed.